# COM Object Registration--Multiple allowed?

Tags: c#, windows, com, vb6

I have two COM objects with different `GUID` values, but the same name. One is a newer version of the other. What happens when I register both using `Name.exe /regserver`? I've looked in the registry, and they both show up with the same `ProgID`, but their respective `GUID` values are different. They point to their separate locations on the hard drive. Is this a problem?

I'm trying to get the old version of a project to work alongside the new version of a project (but not running at the same time), and I think these two things are fighting.

The COM objects were created in VB6. The code that uses them is C#. They are added to their individual C# projects as references. When one is registered, I can't compile the other (nor run successfully).

What other information would be helpful while investigating this issue?

Comment: AFAICR there's a setting in the c# references dialog that allows you to specify that a local copy of the COM component should be used. Another idea: either change ProgId of the new component, or else make it fully backward compatible (binary compatibility setting in VB6) and only distribute the new component.

Comment: @mrtig Are you saying if the C# Assembly is strongly signed, then internally it will use the proper key for the VB6 COM object it references, --or-- are you saying the VB6 COM object should be strongly signed? If the latter is the case, I haven't yet been able to find anyone on the web that claims to be able to strong name a VB6 component.

Comment: @MarkJ I think you are talking about the `Use Embedded Interop` flag. The C# project won't compile if I try to embed these VB6 COM objects. The flag must be set to false. The other problem I run into is the old baseline is alive and well for about half the customers. The new one is for the other half, and the newer version of this COM object has breaking features. I can't really drop one. :-)

Comment: @kmort Yes I was probably thinking of `Use Embedded Interop`. Maybe it doesn't work for ActiveX Exes - I think you are creating ActiveX Exes from VB6? OK. If the new component has breaking features, and it must be able to coexist with the old component, then it really should have a different ProgID. People often append a `2` to the original ProgID.

Comment: Just to confirm, these are VB6 ActiveX Exes?  Do you have access to the source code for them if you need to modify them?

Comment: @tcarvin Yes, I have the source code and they are ActiveX .exe files built with VB6. I could go on a long rant about how many times I've tried to get management to let me rewrite them in a modern language, but I won't. :-)

Comment: Then I agree with @MarkJ, append a version suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

You have created a new version of a component which is not backward compatible with the old version.

You really should change the `ProgID` to indicate that this is effectively a new component. Client apps will have to explicitly target either the new component or the old one. People often just append a version number (e.g. `2`) to the `ProgId`.

Answer (score 1):

You are violating hard COM rules.  Either your replacement must be an *exact* match with the component you replace.  Or you must generate a new version that:

- Uses a different [Guid] for the coclass, you did that correctly.
- Uses a *different* ProgId, you didn't do that.  Boilerplate is to include a version number in the ProgId itself.  So a Foo.Bar becomes Foo.Bar.2
- Uses *different* [Guids] for the interfaces implemented by the class.  This is easy to overlook since they are hidden so well in a VB6 component.  Crucial however whenever the class is used from another apartment.  COM needs to find the type library for the component so it knows how to marshal the interface method call.  Be sure to declare your interfaces explicitly in your C# code.

The best way to double-check all this is by running OleView.exe, File + View Typelib command.  That decompiles the type library content back to IDL, you will see the guids and interfaces.  If you want to create an exact substitute for the old component then everything must match exactly.  Exact same guids, exact same interfaces with the exact same order of methods and exact same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever accessed VB6 ActiveX exes from .NET (just dlls), so this is a shot in the dark (and is weak enough to be just a comment except it is too long).

Perhaps you can create / export a .tlb each for the two VB6 components to compile your C# against.  You shouldn't need the exes to compile.

Next manually add the registry entries as if they had separate Programmatic IDs (say `MyComponent.ServerClass.1` and `MyComponent.ServerClass.2`) and then load them by name in your C#.